# What does `${@+"${@}"}` mean in bash scripting?

Tags: bash

Can someone explain what `${@+"${@}"}` is in bash?

I apologize if this question is a duplicate due to this type of expression having a "name" it can be referred to.

Comment: I believe this link has the answer: https://linuxhint.com/bash-scripting-symbols/

Comment: Just testing it out, it seems to be exactly the same as `$@`, which is a string containing all the arguments passed to the shell script or function.  The relevant documentation is here but I can't find any info about what the `+` does:  [Sell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), [Special Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html)

Comment: @DavidGrayson `${a+b}` is basically `if a is defined then b else ""`. It is documented under your first link. See `${parameter:+word}` and the description of what happens when "Omitting the colon".